# error: A hook (`userconfig`) failed to load and module export

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

info: Winston logger has been started on Ridepal
error: A hook (`userconfig`) failed to load!
error: Failed to lift app: Error: When using `aggregate`, modules must export dictionaries.  But module (`scala\route-matcher`) is invalid:function `matchesRoute(testRoute) { console.log("testRoute", testRoute); return routes.some((route) => route.match(testRoute)); }`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2KmI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: adding the screenshort